# pandas - find first occurrence count per user

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

i have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
 userID   value   step
  1        bad     1
  1        bad     2
  1        good    3
  2        good    1
  2        bad     2
  ...
  3000     good    200
```

a user scores a value for multiple times. It can be bad or good and there is step number tracking the number of times a user scores.

I want to find the first time in the step that a user scores good for each user. For example, for user 1, it will be 3, for user 2, it will be 1, etc.

And then calculate the fraction of first step/total step of a user. For example, for the first user, it will be 3/3, for the second user, it will be 1/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is replace `step` values by missing values by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) if no match `good` compared by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for first non `NaN` value and counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), divide in [`DataFrame.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) and last convert `Series` to `Dataframe` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.assign(new = df['step'].where(df['value'].eq('good')))
        .groupby('userID')
        .agg({'new':'first', 'value':'size'})
        .eval('new / value')
        .reset_index(name='score')
        )
print (df)
   userID  score
0       1    1.0
1       2    0.5
2    3000  200.0
```